# What does it mean that the weight function has infinitely many points of increase?

Tags: integration, inner-products

Define the inner product:

$<f,g>=\int^{a}_{b} f(x) g(x) dw(x).   \quad   (1)$

What does it mean the following statement?

"we assume that $w $ has infinitely many points of increase, in order to ensure that (1) is an inner product"

Could you please explain it? why do we need a weight function?

Answer (score 1):

If $w$ is constant on some subinterval $[c,d] \subseteq [b,a]$, then for any function $f$ supported on $[c,d]$ we have $\langle f, f \rangle = 0$ but $f \not \equiv 0$.

Comment: Do you mean the $w$ should be distinct points in the interval? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @Momo If $w(x)=x$ then you get the usual integral, so $\langle f, f \rangle = \int_b^a (f(x))^2 \, dx$ is zero only if $f$ is zero (almost everywhere). This happens because $w$ is strictly increasing. If instead $w$ is a constant function, then $\langle f, f \rangle = 0$ even if $f$ is not the zero function, which is undesirable. This also is a problem if $w$ is constant on some interval $[c,d]$; we will have $\langle f, f \rangle = 0$ for any $f$ that is zero outside of $[c,d]$.

Comment: Thank you very much. How do we know that $w$ is strictly increasing?